# Pycharm breakpoints hang when executed code is inside of a function

Tags: debugging, pycharm

When using Pycharm's debugger, the breakpoints hang if the code being inspected is inside of a function.

If I have a file with the code:

```
print("Hello")

print("World")  # Breakpoint here
```

And I start a debugging REPL, it prints "Hello", then automatically switches to the "Deubgger" tab and shows the variables in scope. This is what I expect to happen.

If I put it in a function though:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello")

    print("World")  # Breakpoint here
```

And then start a  debugger REPL and call `hello`, it prints "Hello" then nothing happens. It just sits there. If I switch to the "Debugger" tab in the console, it's empty except for a "Connected" with an icon in the "Variables" box.

If I leave it long enough, it just seemingly silenty fails and exits the function?:

```
>>> hello()
Hello
       # A few minutes later

>>>    # "World" is never printed and it returns.
```

This is the first time I've used Pycharm's debugger, but I've used IntelliJ's, and it worked as I expected. This issue has survived restarting both the computer.

Does anyone know why the debugger is hanging is this case?

Comment: What's the *PyCharm* version? Works fine on *v2019.2.3*. Also what's the file name?

Comment: @CristiFati Not at my computer currently. It was the latest release though; I had an update recently. And the file I was in was called `dev_test.py`.